# How to reload one table view row select then another tableview reload?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Below is my sample code. How to reload `tblview`(tableview)? Please help me.

```
@interface NewUIViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblview;
- (IBAction)btnAddRow:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblviewProject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *projectArray;
@end
@interface NewUIViewController ()
    {   }
@end
@implementation NewUIViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Tiger",@"Leopard",@"Snow Leopard",@"Lion",nil];
    self.projectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test1",@"test12",@"test1 Leopard",@"test13",nil];];     
    self.tblview.delegate= self;
    self.tblview.dataSource=self;   
    self.tblviewProject.delegate= self;
    self.tblviewProject.dataSource =self;
    self.tblviewProject.frame = CGRectMake(50, 150, 600, 600);
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return  YES;
}
- (NSUInteger ) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tblview)
    {
    return [self.dataArray count];
    }
    else if (tableView == self.tblviewProject)
    {
        return [self.projectArray count];
    }
    return 0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.editingAccessoryType = YES;
        if (tableView == self.tblview)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text =  [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         }
        else if (tableView == self.tblviewProject)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.projectArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
        }        
    }   
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    if(tableView == self.tblviewProject)
    {     
        NSMutableDictionary *newDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *rowchange = (NSDictionary *) [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:[self.projIndexPath intValue]];
        [newDic addEntriesFromDictionary:rowchange];
        [newDic setObject:pname forKey:project];       
        [self.tblview beginUpdates];
        [self.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[self.projIndexPath intValue] withObject:newDic];         
        [self.tblview reloadData];
        [self.tblview endUpdates];   
    }
}
@end
```

[image]

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question to property format the code and read the guidelines. No one can read what you've posted and can therefor not help you.

Comment: Please add a brief description on what you want to achieve as your question is unclear due to poor grammar. You want to reload 2nd table view when user clicks on a row in 1st table view?

Comment: 2nd table view click first table view reload. remove and create working fine. but not replace or change the existing record values doesn't reload the first table.

Answer (score -1):

In you didSelectRowAtIndexPath func ,What 's `pname`  and `projIndexPath`
And self.dataArray is NSString array but you `replaceObjectAtIndex` with a dictionary, it 's not correct
I don't know what do you want?

Update: you function runing but don't mean it 's correct
 In `Cellforrowatindexpath` you set

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But you replace a item in self.dataArray with a dictionary ==> you think, it 's working?
try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.tblviewProject)
    {
        [self.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:self.projectArray[indexPath.row]];
        [self.tblview reloadData];
    }
}
```

and replace pnam and projIndexPath as you want

AXXXXXXXXXXX
Update cellforrowat

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.editingAccessoryType = YES;
    }
    if (tableView == self.tblview)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =  [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (tableView == self.tblviewProject){
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.projectArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I's sure this working, when you reloaddata for tableview, cell is not nil, so, it 's not set data for cell

Comment: pname  means tblviewProject select index value and projIndexPath means tblview indexpath values. My functionality working for replaceObjectAtIndex  but did not reload tblview . how to reaload data. please help me

Comment: [self.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:self.projectArray[indexPath.row]];
        [self.tblview reloadData];  
  it's replace the dataArray object index but did not relaod the tblview. please help me.

Comment: dataArray(tblview1) and projectArray(tblview2)
  tblview2 row values select and change  tblview1 second index values
  below is my example steps
  tblview1 itmes are test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7....
  tblview2 items are newtest1,newtest2,newtest3,........
  tblview2  -> select newtest3 values to change the tblview1 items are test1, newtest3 ,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7
  tblview2  -> select newtest1 values to change the tblview1 items are test1, newtest1 ,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7

Comment: Am one new row add and one row delete is reload data. but modify the row doesn't reload data. please help me

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.tblviewProject)
    {
        [self.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:self.projectArray[indexPath.row]];
        [self.tblview reloadData];
    }
}
it's replace the array values. but not reload tblview.